# Women collaborators within China during the Second Sino-Japanese War?

Tags: world-war-two, china, social-history

There are several reports of women collaborators in Europe during the Nazi occupation. I am wondering if there is any reports of this occurring in China, and what possibly happened to these women after the war?

Comment: [There's at least one, arguably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshiko_Kawashima): Yoshiko Kawashima was a Chinese princess of Manchu descent. She was raised in Japan and served as a spy for the Japanese Kwantung Army and puppet state of Manchukuo during the Second Sino-Japanese War. She is sometimes known in fiction under the pseudonym "Eastern Mata Hari". After the war, she was captured, tried and executed as a traitor by the Nationalist government of the Republic of China.